# Why does Google GCP create Storage Legacy roles by default when creating a new bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Lets assume one create a brand new project in the present (July 2021). After creating a new bucket, clicking on Permissions shows:

```
 Storage Legacy Bucket Owner 
 Storage Legacy Object Owner 
 Storage Legacy Bucket Reader 
 Storage Legacy Object Reader
```

Given this is a new Google account and new project etc, why is it creating legacy roles, given that non legacy role versions exist too?

Is this something to be concerned with?

Comment: One reason is that legacy authorization is still supported in Google Cloud. Another reason is that some of the legacy roles are easier to use for GCP beginners than the newer fine-grained IAM roles. Do not assume the word `Legacy` means `ancient and should be replaced`. Instead, think first-generation and second-generation. Use the roles that contain the permissions you require.

Comment: That makes sense, Thanks John.

Answer (score 1):

This is because as @Jhon Hanley explained in the comment,

> One reason is that legacy authorization is still supported in Google
> Cloud. Another reason is that some of the legacy roles are easier to
> use for GCP beginners than the newer fine-grained IAM roles. Do not
> assume the word Legacy means ancient and should be replaced. Instead,
> think first-generation and second-generation. Use the roles that
> contain the permissions you require.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a bucket, this is a manual process and it is expected that you should know what you are doing as average users would simply use the same bucket with different folders. The idea behind this is to let you create buckets in a live production environment without fully exposing it until you are ready to do so per your own design, it would be ideal if we could clone another bucket with their roles, but this is a caveat for full customization.